# Linux Ubuntu LTS ODBC Microsoft sql

Tags: odbc

```
Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
```

From my Ubuntu machine I want to access an MS SQL 2005 server via ODBC. This MSSQL server is on our internal network. I've installed these packages: unixodbc, unixodbc-dev, unixodbc-bin, libodbc1, libtool, autotools-dev and several other dependencies. Also tdsodbc, freetds-bin, freetds-common, freetds-dev, libct4.

But I can't seem to find where the .so file is to use it in my DSN in /etc/odbc.ini. Which file do I use? Doing this: echo "select 1"|isql -v mydsn gives me this error:

```
[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so' : file not found
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

The 'mydsn' is trying to point to /usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so but it's not there. Which .so file do I set up in the /etc/odbc.ini file?

Answer (score 0):

According to this link: http://www.unixodbc.org/doc/FreeTDS.html, it might be:

```
/usr/local/freetds/lib/libtdsodbc.so
```

Another possibility is:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
```

This is for 64-bits architecture.

Once you found the right place, update the /etc/odbcinst.ini to reflect the changes.